# Creating a string constant to ALL language strings.xml in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, string, android-studio

When I have to make a new string constant in a project I often use to simply write down the reference first just like: `R.sring.my_new_string` then I use **Alt + Enter** to pop up this dialog:

[image]

The problem is, as you can see **only the default 'values' is selected when the dialog pops** and I **have to select the other 'values-it'** (Italian strings) manualy to create the same string resource to that file too.

**Of course this results in a deficient 'values-it/strings.xml' file because a lot of times I simply forget to select the checkbox.**

Is there a way to somehow **set Android Studio to always create the string resource for EVERY strings.xml** in the project?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *... to create the same string resource to that file too.* with the same value? what for ?

Comment: @Selvin If the same string is not present in the other strings.xml the translators cannot translate it. - Because it's not even there.

Comment: @Selvin what is this? Looks promising

Comment: Open default `strings.xml` in xml editor, then click "Open editor" (AS 2.2)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Press that to select all.
That doesn't solve your problem?
Happy coding!

Comment: No it does not save this setting, you have to click it each and every time manually.